# about extracting things from strings.. (Extracting integers from strings)

Tags: string, awk, sed, extract, numerical

In bash I'm trying to extract some data from strings like this:

```
OK - C: Total=49.90GB, Used=42.53GB (85.2%), Free=7.36GB (14.8%)     |'C: Space'=42.53GB; 'C: Utilisation'=85.2%;
```

I would like to extract `49.90,42.53` and `7.36`, or even better `49,42` and `7`.

With some awk like `'/=/{print $4}'` I get

```
Total=49.90GB
```

Is there a way to extract only the numerical string with one command?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `gawk` and `match(target,regex,array)` function:

```
awk '{match($0,/.*Total=([^.]+).*Used=([^.]+).*Free=([^.]+).*/,a);print a[1],a[2],a[3]}' input_file
49 42 7
```

Or you can use `grep` to store the values in different variables:

```
var1=$(grep -oP 'Total=\K[^.]+' input)
var2=$(grep -oP 'Free=\K[^.]+' input)
var3=$(grep -oP 'Used=\K[^.]+' input)
```

Comment: thanks..it works, but -shame on me- there is an easy way to set these values ​​to variables $A $B $C in the same string? Sorry i had to ask it before. I'm a newbie..

Comment: replace `.*Total=([^.]+).*Used=([^.]+).*Free=([^.]+).*` with `.*Total=([^.]+).*` to get the value of total. Similary you can get fot others. Check update.

Comment: Great!Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Some more way, using `RS` / `match()` / looping through fields

Input:

```
$ cat infile
OK - C: Total=49.90GB, Used=42.53GB (85.2%), Free=7.36GB (14.8%)     |'C: Space'=42.53GB; 'C: Utilisation'=85.2%;
```

> I would like to extract 49.90,42.53 and 7.36, or even better 49,42 and
>   7.

**Using `RS`**

Output-1:

```
# for-I would like to extract 49.90,42.53 and 7.36,
$ awk -v RS=' ' -F'=' -v OFS=','   'c==3{exit}/^(Total|Used|Free)=/{c++; gsub(/GB|,/,"",$2); printf("%s%s",$2,c==3?"\n":OFS)}' infile
49.90,42.53,7.36
```

Output-2:

```
# for - or even better 49,42 and 7.
$ awk -v RS=' ' -F'=' -v OFS=','   'c==3{exit}/^(Total|Used|Free)=/{c++; gsub(/\..*/,"",$2); printf("%s%s",$2,c==3?"\n":OFS)}' f2
49,42,7
```

Better Readable:

```
awk -v RS=' ' -F'=' -v OFS=','   '
              c==3{exit}
              /^(Total|Used|Free)=/{
                      c++; 
                      gsub(/GB|,/,"",$2); 
                      printf("%s%s",$2,c==3?"\n":OFS)
              }
              ' infile
```

**Using `match`**

```
$ awk -v OFS=, '{s="";while(match($0,/(Total|Used|Free)=[^ ,]+/)){t=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); gsub(/.*=|GB/,"",t); s=(s?s OFS:"") t;$0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}print s}' infile
49.90,42.53,7.36
```

Better Readable:

```
awk -v OFS=, '{
                s="";
                while(match($0,/(Total|Used|Free)=[^ ,]+/)){
                     t=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); 
                     gsub(/.*=|GB/,"",t);
                     s=(s?s OFS:"") t;
                     $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
                 }
                 print s
               }
              ' infile
```

**By looping through fields**

```
$ awk -v OFS=, '{s="";for(i=1; i<=NF;i++)if($i~/(Total|Used|Free)=/){ gsub(/.*=|GB|,/,"",$i); s=(s?s OFS:"") $i;} print s}' infile
49.90,42.53,7.36
```

Better Readable:

```
awk -v OFS=, '{
               s="";
               for(i=1; i<=NF;i++)
                   if($i~/(Total|Used|Free)=/)
                   { 
                     gsub(/.*=|GB|,/,"",$i); 
                     s=(s?s OFS:"") $i;
                   } 
                print s
               }
              ' infile
```

**Explanation:**

- `RS=' '` - set row separator as single space
- `-F'='`  - set field/column separator as `=`
- `-v OFS=','` -set output field/column separator as comma `,`

By default `awk` use `\n` newline char as row separator, but here we force awk to read space as row separator, so when you set space as row separator awk reads your file as follows

```
$ awk -v RS=' ' '{print "Line No:",NR,"=>", $0}' f2
Line No: 1 => OK
Line No: 2 => -
Line No: 3 => C:
Line No: 4 => Total=49.90GB,
Line No: 5 => Used=42.53GB
Line No: 6 => (85.2%),
Line No: 7 => Free=7.36GB
Line No: 8 => (14.8%)
Line No: 9 => 
Line No: 10 => 
Line No: 11 => 
Line No: 12 => 
Line No: 13 => |'C:
Line No: 14 => Space'=42.53GB;
Line No: 15 => 'C:
Line No: 16 => Utilisation'=85.2%;
```

- `c==3{exit}` when variable c equals to 3, exit
- `/^(Total|Used|Free)=/` if a row/record/line start with any one in the list, then
- `c++` post increment counter variable, single we want 3 fields, when it becomes 3, we just put newline char in our printf statement
- `gsub(/GB|,/,"",$2);` global substitution, replace GB or comma with null in second column
- `printf("%s%s",$2,c==3?"\n":OFS)` till variable `c` becomes 3, we print second column, and output field separator (`,`), when `c` becomes 3, we are done, so print newline char.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for FPAT:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[0-9.]+' '{print $1, $2, $4}' file
49.90 42.53 7.36

$ awk -v FPAT='[0-9.]+' '{printf "%d %d %d\n", $1, $2, $4}' file
49 42 7
```